# "custom" routers for VPN - useful or waste of money?

Tags: router, vpn

I use VPN in China and my current service contract expires soon so I was checking what sort of plans are out there now. I found that Witopia offers a ["Cloak Box"](http://www.witopia.net/index.php/products/), what appears to be a Linksys wireless router with allegedly hacked/custom firmware to support VPN.

Aside from allowing multiple computers to share one VPN connection, is there anything else at work here to justify that price when most new routers are $100 or less these days?

Or is this something targeted towards the cd-rom cupholder crowd?

And yes, I've contacted them, but haven't heard back yet...

EDIT

I've heard back from the company - here are the details if anyone else is interested:

- the router is a Linksys WRT54GL running TomatoVPN custom firmware
- the hardware waranty is one (1) year, from Linksys/Cisco
- the VPN is hard-set, so any device connected to the router MUST use the VPN (Witopia blocks torrents)

I've decided it's not for me, but hopefully this information will prove useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would never, EVER, trust a security VPN device I did not personally configured.

tl;dr - Security is too serious to trust to a el cheapo device.

Call me a paranoid freak, but it is much too easy for some third-party to buy share in the company and/or bribe the right people and - voila - you have a backdoor in your VPN.

For instance, let's take TOR: there is a conflict of interest going on TOR (The Onion Router) as well. One of the main contributors works for Wikileaks, which has an opposite mission as TOR. And there are proven successful attacks agains TOR if you run a bunch of supernodes.

More details in: http://sheddingbikes.com/posts/1293530004.html

Answer (score 1):

Just get [this](https://www.server4you.de/vserver/). It's dirt cheap, seriously. (Much cheaper than such things like you mention AND you can do ANYTHING with it since it's a full VPN.)

Comment: When I tried to use your link Firefox popped up the "www.server4you.com uses an invalid security certificat" screen.

Comment: Uhm what about it? I mean.. whats the problem with that? Anyway, their certification is VALID. Check your PC/browser/your PC's date settings. (Verified by the USERTRUST network)

Answer (score 0):

It would appear to be $100 for the pre-configured router plus $100, for 1 year of service at $100/year.  Presumably they charge more for service with their router than for your computer because they expect you to hang your whole LAN off of it.